# Do not have the master key of Parse app

Tags: parse-platform

I know I should have done this before. But I didn't get a chance to host parse and now when I am trying to do it, it is asking to enter me master key, but I do not have it. I have parse channel name, client key, application id, javascript key. Is it possible to host a parse server using these keys only or is there any way to get master key now? Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your own master key when you host a parse server.  It can be anything you want.
If you mean you want to keep the existing master key from a parse.com app,  there is no way to do this unless you have a record of it.  For instance if you used it somewhere.